# How to Perform Vulnerability Assessment for WCF services

Tags: penetration-test, tools, vulnerability-scanners

Does anyone know how to perform penetration testing/vulnerability assessment  for Microsoft WCF services I couldn't find a tools till now , any tools available and guides are welcome

Comment: Related: [Is WCF or Java Metro security configuration in-scope for your security department; should it be?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/738/396)

Answer (score 7):

Beyond basic SOAP fuzzers there aren't too many advanced tools useful for pen testing of a WCF service. Since WCF/SOAP is really just a front for the underlying API you've written, you really need a tool to assess the vulnerabilities in your API, which is usually something of a custom nature.

There are tools out there like FxCop which have a very simple baseline for security analysis, but you can't rely on it entirely.

There's a great intro presentation on the OWASP site by Brian Holyfield about pen testing WCF services here: https://www.owasp.org/images/6/6c/Attacking_WCF_Web_Services-Brian_Holyfield.pdf. He lists a couple tools, but they aren't WCF/SOAP specific.

Comment: i found this to be useful also http://www.gremwell.com/blog/pentesting_silverlight_and_wcf_ria what do you think

Comment: The tools it lists are pretty good. They are normally used for regular testing.